# mouseleave being triggered immediately after mouseenter

Tags: javascript

When using event listeners for mouseenter and mouseleave, after window.onblur is triggered, a mouseenter triggers a mouseleave every time.

Any solution to this?

Example [here](https://eskimo.dev/example)

Sorry for external link, but mouseenter/mouseleave don't work in a snippet after onblur.

Comment: Can't reproduce on your example

Comment: Seems this only occurs on chrome, not firefox. Also, I'm running macOS, not sure if that's part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Tak a look at this !! From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

```js
var enterEventCount = 0;
var leaveEventCount = 0;
const mouseTarget = document.getElementById('mouseTarget');
const unorderedList = document.getElementById('unorderedList');

mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  mouseTarget.style.border = '5px dotted orange';
  enterEventCount++;
  addListItem('This is mouseenter event ' + enterEventCount + '.');
});

mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  mouseTarget.style.border = '1px solid #333';
  leaveEventCount++;
  addListItem('This is mouseleave event ' + leaveEventCount + '.');
});

function addListItem(text) {
  // Create a new text node using the supplied text
  var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(text);

  // Create a new li element
  var newListItem = document.createElement("li");

  // Add the text node to the li element
  newListItem.appendChild(newTextNode);

  // Add the newly created list item to list
  unorderedList.appendChild(newListItem);  
}
```

```css
#mouseTarget {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:15rem;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id='mouseTarget'>
 <ul id="unorderedList">
  <li>No events yet!</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```